# 1. Text file is not getting updated once is loaded as a class variable, 2. How to attach string to file without sp.chars

Tags: python, string, class, kivy, kivy-language

I am relatively new to coding. Just a couple of Months. I am good with many things just started with classes and tried to create mobile app in Kivy. So the same app in Tkinter was easier but once i rewritten code to Kivy syntax and classes it got a bit harder.

So after 3 days of trying different approaches I would like to ask for your help. 
I've added both files on GitHub:
https://github.com/UnryMF/7-Wonders-Assistant

1. I don't know how to update class variable which is reading content of text file.
   >

   > `One of the screens to load and present results:`
   >   
   >   class ResultsScreen(BoxLayout, Screen):
   >
   > ```
   > with open('test.txt', 'r') as display:
   >     display_contents = display.read()
   >
   > pass
   > ```

In kivy

> 

```
<ResultsScreen>
    name: 'Results'
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 25, 25
    spacing: 5

BoxLayout:
    Label:
        text: root.display_contents
        multiline: True
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        text: "Back"
        size_hint: 1, 0.4
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "WManager"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "up"
```

My question is how to reload this file into memory (currently it reads version before updates done by other functions) after reload of app its being read again.

2. This might be less complicated. 
   Once I am adding matching results into text file it kept all special characters which are not wanted.

> self.add = self.i, 'will play', self.wonder,random.choice(AdvancedWindow.ab)
>   Then when I am adding this to file:
>
> > ('Player1', 'will play', 'the Lighthouse of Alexandria', 'A')
>
> Desired outcome would be the same that is when print is being used.
>   print(self.i, 'will play', self.wonder, '(', random.choice(AdvancedWindow.ab), ')')
>
> > Player1 will play the Mausoleum at Halicarnassus ( B )

Source code is added on GitHub. If you have any ideas how I can fix this part of code I would be grateful.

Comment: ResultsScrren is showing old data which are available in file before compilation. I've all formula in constructor to load file and its content. but how to refresh it and reload ? I've tried to write function reload() but cannot define parapeters and dont know where it should be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I completely understand your question, but if you are trying to get your display to update when you re-read the `test.txt` file, then you can use a Kivy `Property`:

```
class ResultsScreen(BoxLayout, Screen):
    display_contents = StringProperty('')

with open('test.txt', 'r') as display:
    self.display_contents = display.read()
```

This assumes that your `with open` is part of the `ResultsScreen` class.

As for the second question, I think you can just replace the `,` separators with a '+' in your line that defines `self.add`. Otherwise, you are creating a list, not a line of text.

Comment: Hi @John , replacing separators works fine for self.add. Big thanks for that.  About first part if I set StringProperty as ' '  then no value is presented on ResultsScreen basically whatever is in () it will be presented. I've tried that before and value is still not updated maybe need to initiate something while class is called.

Comment: The line of code: `self.display_contents = display.read()` should update the `StringProperty`, which should then update the `Label`.

Comment: I've tried that and it wasn't updating. So i tried many other things that came into my head. `class ResultsScreen(BoxLayout, Screen):

    display_contents = StringProperty('default')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ResultsScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with open('test.txt', 'r') as self.display:
            self.display_contents = self.display.read()
    pass`    This is working but also shows previous version of file. I had to add self to display.  Maybe there is another way to call with open or I should implement a function there.

Comment: or i need to close file in order to open it again with changes?